# ウェブサイトの記事投稿をデータ入力で自動生成させたいです

Tags: wordpress

ワードプレスでDIVERというテーマを使用して「性犯罪者ドットコム」というサイトを作成しています。
現状では性加害者一人につき手動で投稿ページを編集しているのですが、非常に労力を使います。

そこで、エクセルのようなシートにデータ（氏名、年齢、犯行現場、裁判判決等）を入力することで、その行のデータを基に投稿ページを自動生成するような仕様は実現可能でしょうか？

ワードプレスやテーマにこだわりはありません。

もし実現可能なら、どのような言語の習得が必要になりますか？
また、方法として大まかでいいので、どのような方法があるか教えていただけると嬉しいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/r3qm8kem612xwo) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: cubick様

他のサイトも確認してからコメントしてくれたのですね！ありがとうございます！
おっしゃる通り、他のサイトで質問に対するコメントがつきまして、

CSVからWordPressで投稿と検索してみたら、下記のページがヒットしました。 https://pro.alcuesto.jp/wp-all-import/  なんとなく実現方法が見えてきましたので、同じ悩みを抱えている方にシェアいたします。 コメントしていただいた〇〇○様、ありがとうございました。

上記のように、道筋が見えてきたところです。
cubick様のお心遣いに感謝いたします。ありがとうございました。